# Improving node.js code (sequelize, promises and passport)

Tags: node.js, authentication, promise, sequelize.js

I'm a newbie in node.js, sequelize, Bluebird promises and FB authentication.

I'd like to persist my FB authenticated user with some authentication details.

In my model, one user can have many authentications at the same time (one for the browser, another for the mobile, etc).
I need to take care of these authentications, so I have the next relationships:

User.hasMany(Auth);
Auth.belongsTo(User);

I wrote this code that works, but i'm still looking for an smarter solution.

The main goal is to add the authentication information to the user.
So, before peristing the auth info, I look for a persisted user.

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        console.log("FacebookStrategy_function:\naccessToken: " + accessToken);

    var thatUser=null;

        User.find({
          where: {
            username: profile.username 
          },
          include: [{model: Auth}]
        }).then(function(user) {
          console.log("USER IS #1: %j", user);
          if(user!= null){  // User found in database
            console.log("User " + profile.id + "found in database");
            return user;
          }else{  // First time that user authenticate in app
          var user = User.build({
              username: profile.username,
              givenName: profile.name.givenName,
              familyName: profile.name.familyName
            });
            return user.save();
          }
        }).then(function(user) {
          console.log("USER IS #2: %j", user);
          thatUser=user;

          var auth= Auth.build({
            provider: 'facebook',
            providerId: profile.id,
            accessToken: accessToken
          });

          return user.addAuth(auth);
        }).then(function(auth){
          user=thatUser;
          console.log("USER IS #3: %j", user);
          console.log("done. user and association saved.  auth is: %j", auth);


          done(null, user); // Call FacebookEstrategy's done
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("\nsomething happened persisting user/auth " + err);
            done(err, null); // Propagate error to FacebookEstrategy
        });

      }
```

Having the next log:

```
    FacebookStrategy_function: accessToken: CAACO...
    Executing (default): SELECT "Users".*, "Auths"."id" AS "Auths.id", ... WHERE     "Users"."username"='john.doe'...
    INSERT INTO "Users" ("id","username","givenName","familyName","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,'john.doe',...)
    USER IS #1: null
    Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Users"     ("id","username","givenName","familyName","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,'john.doe',...)
    USER IS #2: {"username":"john.doe","givenName":"John","familyName":"Doe","id":2,"updatedAt":"2014-11-09T19:12:23.250Z","createdAt":"2014-11-09T19:12:23.250Z"}
    Executing (default): SELECT * FROM "Auths" WHERE "UserId" = 2;
    Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Auths" ("id","provider","providerId","accessToken","createdAt","updatedAt","UserId") VALUES (DEFAULT,'facebook','...','CAACO...','2014-11-09 19:12:23.278 +00:00','2014-11-09 19:12:23.278 +00:00',2) RETURNING *;
    USER IS #3: {"username":"john.doe","givenName":"John","familyName":"Doe","id":2,"updatedAt":"2014-11-09T19:12:23.250Z","createdAt":"2014-11-09T19:12:23.250Z"}
    done. user and association saved.  auth is: {"provider":"facebook","providerId":"...","accessToken":"CAACO...","id":2,"UserId":2,"updatedAt":"2014-11-09T19:12:23.278Z","createdAt":"2014-11-09T19:12:23.278Z"}
```

For me was to wierd to handle, that user.addAuth(auth) return an auth object.
In the next then method, I expected to receive an user object (instead of auth)
As workaround, I used in the main function scope an awful thatUser variable.
Is there any smarter way to do that?

In logs, the trace "USER IS #3:" is showing an user without its authentications objects.
Why?

Any correction or improvement will be wellcomed

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using promises - you can drop the `done` callback - you can simply return the promise. If you really want the done callback - you can call `.nodeify` instead of explicitly calling it although returning promises has other benefits like unhandled rejection tracking.

You can also use aggregation methods instead of explicit closure scope:

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile) {
    console.log("FacebookStrategy_function:\naccessToken: " + accessToken);
    return User.find({
      where: { username: profile.username }, include: [{model: Auth}]
    }).then(function(user) {
      console.log("USER IS #1: %j", user);
      if(user!= null){  // User found in database
        console.log("User " + profile.id + "found in database");
        return user;
      } 
      return User.build({ // first time
          username: profile.username,
          givenName: profile.name.givenName,
          familyName: profile.name.familyName
        }).save();
    }).then(function(user) {
      console.log("USER IS #2: %j", user);
      var auth= Auth.build({
        provider: 'facebook',
        providerId: profile.id,
        accessToken: accessToken
      });
      return [user, user.addAuth(auth)]; // note the array
    }).spread(function(user, auth){ // note the spread
      console.log("USER IS #3: %j", user);
      console.log("done. user and association saved.  auth is: %j", auth);
      return user;
    });
}
```

Now, if I'm allowed to drop all the `console.log`s, this gets much shorter:

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile) {
  return User.find({
      where: { username: profile.username }, include: [{model: Auth}]
  }).then(function(user) {
    return user || User.build({ // first time
      username: profile.username,
      givenName: profile.name.givenName,
      familyName: profile.name.familyName
    }).save();
  }).then(function(user) {
    return Auth.build({
      provider: 'facebook',
      providerId: profile.id,
      accessToken: accessToken
    }).return(user);
  });
}
```